# Setting up an irc where only people with a certain Vhost can talk

Tags: centos, security, irc

Well after trying out, ircd-hybrid, Unrealircd and inspircd. I could still not do what I need for my irc server.

I need to make a secure channel / server. what I want to do is I want to have it so only users with a specified Vhost are allowed to speak (server wide).

I.E:

- User@1.1.1.1-att.com (this user cannot speak in the server)
- User@vhost.com (This user can speak, preferably a Oper.)

This brings me to my next question. could I just make it so only Oper users can talk server-wide?

Also I can add I am running Centos 5.9 64bit on a CNserver.
And I do NOT want to add services (Like anope, hybrserve, or any other)

Comment: What particular problem *in a professional environment* are you attempting to solve?

Comment: "I do not want to add services" <- everything from registration to setting opers properly onwards relies on this. *Not* getting services practically cripples your irc server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be blunt: You're Doing It ***WRONG***.

IRC already has a facility for restricting who can speak in channels (two of them in fact -- Voice (`+v`) and Operator (`+o`))
You can combine these with other common IRC tools (like eggdrop bots) to op and/or voice authorized individuals, and whether that's what you *want* or not is irrelevant, it's *how it **should** be done*.

Using the host mask to control this is woefully insecure (and woe be upon the folks who configure their eggdrop bots to trust hostmasks).
I can change my hostmask to be whatever I want (because I happen to have control over my reverse DNS, and the username is arbitrary data supplied by the client).  Relying on that as a security mechanism is thus fundamentally flawed.

---

The alternative, making it so only operators can talk server-wide, is also an option, though not one you would be able to exercise if you were to become part of a larger "normal" IRC network.
Implementing this solution would require some custom edits to the ircd source code, and is left as an exercise for the reader.